# The meaning of first derivative involving area.

Tags: derivatives, area

Given that the equation for the area of a rectangle, A $$A=xy$$ and $$y = 5-\frac{5}{12}x$$ Combine these two formula we get that $$A=5x-\frac{5}{12}x^2$$ and the first derivative will be $$\frac{dA}{dx}=5-\frac{5}{6}x$$ In order to find the maximum area,let $\frac{dA}{dx}=0$ and $x=6$. But the question is how can the value of $\frac{dA}{dx}$ be zero. It should be representing the value of $y$ since $\frac{A}{x}=y$, we know that from the first equation $A=xy$ and the value of $y$ will never be zero. If it doesn't represent the value of $y$, then what it could be?

Comment: $\frac{dA}{dx}$ is the derivative of the function $A(x)$ and it has nothing to do with $\frac Ax$.

Comment: I hope you did not simply cancel the $d$ in $\frac{dA}{dx}$ to get $\frac Ax$.

Comment: But why in the graph of distance against time the gradient of the graph stand for the value of velocity?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is just a simple optimization question. As @Sassatelli Giulio said in the comments, $A(x)$ has nothing to do with $A/x$.

---

Assuming I understand the question right, it asks what the maximum area is given that
$$A(x,y) = xy$$
and
$$y = 5 - \frac{5x}{12}$$

We can plug in the function $y$ to get an expression for the area in terms of $x$ simply by doing what you did
$$A(x) = 5\left(x-\frac{x^2}{12}\right)$$
To find the maximim value of this function we differentiate to get
$$\frac{dA}{dx}= 5\left(1-\frac{x}{6}\right)$$

Then, as you did you set $$\frac{dA}{dx} = 0$$
To find $x = 6$

Then we simply plug these values back into $A(x)$ to find

$$A(6) = 15$$
We see that, therefore, the maximum area is $15$.

1. "How can $\frac{dA}{dx}$ equal zero?" This is simply by solving the equation $$\frac{dA}{dx} = 0$$ and finding that $x=6$
2. The value of $y$ can be zero:
   $$y(x) = 5-\frac{5x}{12}$$
   $$y(12) = 0$$